# Android detect phone lifting action

Tags: android, accelerometer

I want to perform some activity when the user lifts the phone from a flat surface. The method I am using right now is detect shake motion using phone's Accelerometer using the following code:

```
sensorMan = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = sensorMan.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

sensorMan.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_HIGH);

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            mGravity = event.values.clone();
            // Shake detection
            float x = mGravity[0];
            float y = mGravity[1];
            float z = mGravity[2];

            mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
            mAccelCurrent = FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
            float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
            mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta;

            if (mAccel > 0.9) {
                //Perform certain tasks.
            }
        }
```

The issue I am facing with this code is the 0.9f threshold is reached sometimes even if the phone is still on the flat surface. I tried logging the mAccel value and found it to be rannging from 9.0 to 0.4 even when the phone is not even touched. Is there any guaranteed way to detect the phone's lift movement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved the issue. All I wanted to do was to check for the "Y" value stated in the question and check if the value was greater than 1.0.

Note that, if the phone is kept in vertical position the Y is always around 9.8 but in such cases you can check for X instead. In my case user had to lift the phone and somewhen he will tilt the phone so I put a check for if(y >= 1.0 && y <= 2.0);

**EDIT : UPDATED CODE**

```
    @Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    try {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            mGravity = event.values.clone();
            // Shake detection
            float x = mGravity[0];
            float y = mGravity[1];
            float z = mGravity[2];

            float yAbs = Math.abs(mGravity[1]);

            mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
            mAccelCurrent = FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
            float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
            mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta;

            if (yAbs > 2.0 && yAbs < 4.0 && !isAlerted() && !isCallActive()) {
                alert();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that is not encouraged. You should put some efforts in doing that. Anyways, updated.

Comment: For those who are following my answer, please check your app on Micromax phones too. I was facing some issues with them. Micromax sensors are not well calibrated.

Answer (score 2):

I would add the Gyroscope into the detection routine too.

The Phone gets Accelerated **AND** gets up from x=0 y=0 z=0 to, lets say y=120, that's the Trigger.

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-rotate%20here)
for Infos how to using it.

Another Sensor for lifting detection would be the [Proximity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_PROXIMITY) Sensor, when the Phone lays flat on the Desk dinstance would be 0, if its picked up that value would raise quickly

Comment: This won't be of much help @Michele as many phones do not support Gyroscope. Also, proximity sensors will have distance 0 even when they have some flap cover on it. Thanks though.